# csv-file fails to be created after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After converting the code below to an .exe with pyinstaller the program fails to write the csv-file in the output path `data_path_out` from the `dict data = {}` after using the .exe in the dist-folder.

I've tried to link my python file to the test.lnk before and it worked fine.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow7mo.png

```py
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
import pathlib
import csv


data_path_in = pathlib.Path(join(dirname(__file__), "00_Data"))
data_path_out = pathlib.Path(join(dirname(__file__), "01_Results"))


data = {}

with open(join(data_path_in, "Data.txt"), "r") as csv_file:
    r = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter= ",")
    
    for row in r:
        data[row[0]] = row[1]
        
        
with open(join(data_path_out, "Results.txt"), "w") as csv_file:
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect = "excel")
    for key, value in data.items():
        wr.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: Apps converted with Pyinstaller are commonly seen as a virus. Use Nuitka

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using pyinstaller with the `-F` or `--onefile` argument, the global python variable `__file__` does not point to the compiled `.exe` file.

Instead the `__file__` variable points to the the script inside of the runtime directory that is created at runtime in your operating systems temp directories, and which are all automatically destroyed as soon as the program ends.

If you want to create this `.csv` file relative to the compiled `.exe` file created by pyinstaller, use `sys.executable` instead.

```
import os
import sys
from os.path import join, dirname
import pathlib
import csv


data_path_in = pathlib.Path(join(dirname(sys.executable), "00_Data"))
data_path_out = pathlib.Path(join(dirname(sys.executable), "01_Results"))

# you could also write the above 2 lines like this
# data_path_in = Path(sys.executable).parent / "00_Data"
# data_path_out = Path(sys.executable).parent / "01_Results"

data = {}

with open(join(data_path_in, "Data.txt"), "r") as csv_file:
    r = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter= ",")
    
    for row in r:
        data[row[0]] = row[1]
        
        
with open(join(data_path_out, "Results.txt"), "w") as csv_file:
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect = "excel")
    for key, value in data.items():
        wr.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: Hi Alexander. Just tested your solution and it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, apps converted with Pyinstaller are commonly seen as a virus. You can try to use [Nuitka](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka)